# AJAX jQuery does not recognize my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several forms. I try to manage them with AJAX jQuery. I want to minimize the code I use, so I try to use the same AJAX function for all forms. My code does not work. Here's what I have:

**HTML**

```
<form id="mi_forma_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="forma" value="mi_forma_1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="1" />
</form>
<form id="mi_forma_2">
    <input type="hidden" name="forma" value="mi_forma_2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="2" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
id_formulario = null;

  $("input:submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id_del_submit     = $(this).attr('id');  // This having 1 or 2
    id_formulario = '"#mi_forma_'+id_del_submit+'"';
});
   $(id_formulario).on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = $(id_formulario).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
       //...
    });
  });
```

Result: Nothing! When I click the submit, AJAX is not executed. I've done several tests and see that the *id_formulario* variable contains the string **"mi_forma_1"** or **"# mi_forma_2"**.

Why AJAX never executed?

It seems as if the line **$(id_formulario).on("submit"...** does not recognize the value of *id_formulario*.
How to solve this?

Comment: Why use the button events at all...just do `$('form').on('submit'...`. Use a class on form elements if needed or `$('form[id^=mi_form]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an escaped string in `id_formulario`. Use either single or double quotes, but not both except you want those to be part of the string (which you don't).

Change

```
'"#mi_forma_'+id_del_submit+'"'
```

to

```
"#mi_forma_" + id_del_submit
```

Also, since you prevent the default behaviour of the submit buttons, the submit action is probably never performed. Either remove the line or add something like

```
$(id_formulario).trigger("submit")
```

to the submit click event listener.

Last point: you're registering the submit event listener using null as selector, not the value you think. First, you're registering two functions as event listeners. However, you expect the callback of the first listener to be executed before your second listener is registered - this is not happening. The variable `id_formulario` is only changed when a submit button was pressed. However, you do not call `$(id_formulario).on("submit", ...` after that.

---

How I would write it:

```
$("#mi_forma_1, #mi_forma_2").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
       //...
    });
});
```

The referencing through "this" makes sure you're working with the right form. No need to construct any IDs.

Comment: The line: **$().on()** should read: **$("#mi_forma_1").on()**. For this reason I include the double quotes. Anyway, I followed your advice and I have changed line like this: **id_formulario = "#mi_forma_"+id_del_submit.** Still not working.

Comment: I complicate things. You last tip works perfectly! Thanks @Hubert Grzeskowiak

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong, the variable "id_formulario" is started with "null" and your assignation occur only in button click. Remember that ".click" is a event and events are executed only when occur the user action.

```js
var id_formulario = null;

  $("input:submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id_del_submit     = $(this).attr('id');  // This having 1 or 2
    id_formulario = '"#mi_forma_'+id_del_submit+'"';
    
    // editing
    var datos = $(id_formulario).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
       //...
    });
});
```